# restrict the dimensions of image file to be uploaded

Tags: php, file-upload

How do I restrict the image's dimension that is being uploaded via a php script?

I am using cakephp v 1.2

Comment: not really related to CakePHP

Comment: why not, I am doing this in a cakephp application....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you only can check the dimensions after upload with

```
list($imagewidth, $width) = getimagesize("$myupload");
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to wait until the file is uploaded then call [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/getimagesize) to check the dimensions and print an error if it's too big.

You can't check the size before the upload is complete.

Answer (score 2):

Without something on the client side which can see the file system (like a Java applet), you can't know it in advance.

Best you can do is inspect the file with [GetImageSize](http://php.net/getimagesize) after it has been uploaded, but before you do anything important with it.

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

in php you can grab the file dimensions while the file is being uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use:

- AS (ActionScript) (aka Flash)
- Javascript

... to check the dimensions before upload.

Consider always the way of a front-end, PHP should be combined with client-sided tools/languages/apps to make it more efficient. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$maxWidth = 40; // Setted 40px
$maxHeight = 40; // Setted 40px
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name']);

if ($width > $maxWidth || $height > $maxHeight) {
// Cancel upload
}
```